# Crash after resume on Dell Latitude 5175

Tags: suspend, dell, 16.10

I have installed the Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 on a Dell Latitude 5175, a skylake based table with keyboard.

Everything works great apart from when I resume the tablet wakes for a second then crashes, I am able to get to the login screen but I crashes and requires are hard restart.

I have checked the syslog and can see the tablet enter sleep but I don't see any messages around it waking or what the cause of the crash/lockup is.

I have tried updating the kernal and playing around with bios settings but no luck. I am looking for suggestions on how to debug the issue, is it possible to enable more verbose logging?